# How can I make object auto resize in xcode auto layout?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I can't make the **Date Picker** automatically resize its width.
I want the Horizontal constraints showed into the attached images, that is

for **DATE Label**:
Leading Space to Superview = 20
Trailing Space to Date Picker = 20

for **Date Picker**:
Leading Space to DATE Label = 20
Trailing Space to Superview = 20

Xcode says that Width and horizontal position are ambiguous for "Date Picker".
But I don't want a fixed size for the **Date Picker**, I want it resizes itself based on the assigned constraints.

Please help, Thank you!

[image: Date Picker constraints]
[image: Label constraints]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto-layout needs to know which element should get priority for horizontal sizing.

Select your label, and change Horizontal Compression Resistance Priority to Required:

[image]

Comment: As you suggested, I decreased the Content Compression Resistance Priority of the Date Picker and it solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Create constraints like

For the label :

[image]

For the picker :

[image]

When you have a constraint issue click the red arrow it will guide you

[image]